# Using GROUP BY in AWS QLDB / Partiql

Tags: group-by, where-in, amazon-qldb, partiql

I have the following table in my AWS QLDB table:

```
INSERT INTO Testing << {
    'MyId': 1,
    'MyList': [ 'Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3']
},
{
    'MyId': 2,
    'MyList': [ 'Item2', 'Item3', 'Item4']
},
{
    'MyId': 3,
    'MyList': [ 'Item4', 'Item5', 'Item6']
}
>>
```

I need to be able to get all documents which contain a list of items (which do not come from another table), which I'm using the following query for:

```
SELECT *
FROM Testing AS t,
     t.MyList AS l
WHERE l IN ('Item1', 'Item2', 'Item4')
```

However, this gives the following output

```
+------+---------------------------+---------+
| MyId | MyList                    | _3      |
+------+---------------------------+---------+
| 3    | ["Item4","Item5","Item6"] | "Item4" |
+------+---------------------------+---------+
| 1    | ["Item1","Item2","Item3"] | "Item1" |
+------+---------------------------+---------+
| 1    | ["Item1","Item2","Item3"] | "Item2" |
+------+---------------------------+---------+
| 2    | ["Item2","Item3","Item4"] | "Item2" |
+------+---------------------------+---------+
| 2    | ["Item2","Item3","Item4"] | "Item4" |
+------+---------------------------+---------+
```

I want to be able to just get three distinct rows. It would appear based on the error I get when trying to use `DISTINCT` that QLDB doesn't support it, but I also would prefer using `*` in my `SELECT`, So I'm trying to use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT *
FROM Testing AS t,
     t.MyList AS l
WHERE l IN ('Item1', 'Item2', 'Item4')
GROUP BY t.MyId
```

But this gives the following error:

> **Start query error**
>   Semantic Error: at line , column : No such variable named '$__partiql__group_by_1_item_0'; No such variable named '$__partiql__group_by_1_item_0' (Service: AmazonQLDBSession; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: 65vrQHytqHdEL3o9Ym9Xn4)

Answer (score 4):

Neither `DISTINCT` nor `GROUP BY` is not currently supported in QLDB, as indicated by omission from [the SELECT reference.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.select.html) Unfortunately the error message is misleading in this case.

Assuming that your `MyId` column is unique itself, you can express what you want by filtering the lists by checking for inclusion of each item in the list, something like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Testing AS t
WHERE 'Item1' IN t.MyList OR 'Item2' IN t.MyList OR 'Item3' IN t.MyList
```

If you want to further filter the produced lists, you can add a nested `SELECT` with your original filter [as described here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.select.html#ql-reference.select.subqueries):

```sql
SELECT t.MyId, (SELECT VALUE l FROM t.MyList WHERE l IN ('Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3'))
FROM Testing AS t
WHERE 'Item1' IN t.MyList OR 'Item2' IN t.MyList OR 'Item3' IN t.MyList
```

While this is a bit awkward, you likely wouldn't want to do a `GROUP BY` anyway, as that would group across the entire data set (requiring a complete aggregation), when the `items` for each `t` are contained inside of it.